# How to compare the value of selected value in checkbox to a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have to compare the value of selected value in checkbox to a number data which I got from json.

```
var multiQ= new Array();
var questionIndex = 0;
var grade=0;

function updateQuestion(direction) {
    questionIndex += direction;
    if (questionIndex <multiQ.length && questionIndex >= 0) {
        $("#question").html(multiQ[questionIndex].question);
        $('#answers').empty();
        $.each(multiQ[questionIndex].answers, function(key, val) {
            $('#answers').append('<label><input type="checkbox" value="key" id="checkboxid" onchange="test(this)" >' + val + '</label>');
            console.log(typeof(val));

        });
        console.log(multiQ[questionIndex].correct_a);     
    }
    else {
        questionIndex -= direction;
    }
} 
function test() {
                $('input:checked').each(function () {
                    console.log("grade");
                    if (this.value == multiQ[questionIndex].correct_a) {
                        grade=+1;

                    }
                });
            };
```

The test function doesn't work.

Comment: where are you calling ``text()``??

Comment: you are not calling `text()` function anywhere in code

Comment: I forgot to write this... added it.

Comment: where is it failing? if statement? did you print out 'this.value' and 'multiQ[questionIndex].correct_a' to check what's in them?

Comment: @poodle I tried to print in the console this.value. It printed key

Comment: If i understand it correctly. key is the string "key" or some value that you set as key?

Comment: @Sara you want to call test on checkbox check?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - yes. The issue that something is wrong with the test.

Comment: I believe that you right, and key is the string "key

Comment: can you reproduce your issue in a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Sara8/qjnyrqxw/